# expected value and Fisher information.

Tags: calculus, statistics, statistical-inference, fisher-information

Given a sample $ X_1,X_2 \dots X_{100}$ and the density function   $ f(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{\pi \cdot \left(1+\left(x-\theta \right)^2\right)}$ , find Fisher information for  $\hat{\theta}_{MLE.}$

**My attempt**:

$L(\theta;x_1,x_2\dots x_{100}) = \prod _{i=1}^{100}\left(\frac{1}{\pi \cdot \left(1+\left(x_i-\theta \right)^2\right)}\right)\:$

$l$ = $\log(L) = -100*\ln(\pi)-\sum^{100}_{i=1}(\ln(1+(x-\theta)^2)$.

$\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\left(\log(L)\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{100}(\frac{2(x_i-\theta)}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2}$

$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial^2 \theta}\left(\log(L)\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{100}-\frac{2\left(-θ+x_i\right)}{1+\left(x_i-θ\right)^2}$

fisher's information :
$I(\theta) = -E[\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial^2 \theta}\left(\log(L)\right)$

but I don't how to find the expected value, I tried to simplify it but that didn't help.

Comment: What is the problem with writing out the integral and trying to see what it may be?

Comment: You got the second derivative wrong. Check out [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145017/cauchy-distribution-likelihood-and-fisher-information)